# Google Action - unable to connect web hook in Fulfillment Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

This is the message I get when trying to enable webhook with URL (using ngrok)

**You can use only https:// in fulfillment url when "Google Assistant" integration enabled**

So I am unable to save the URL or to use the webhook

However, I have checked that Google Assistant is already integrated...

What should I do?

Comment: What url exactly are you using in Dialogflow fulfillment configuration? Do you prepend it with https://? I am successfully using ngrok for my development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using a secure https url before trying to save.  If you are using ngrok it will gives you two URLs.  Use the one started with https instead of http.  Hope this help!